# Writing my own minimum' function, can't fix a bug

Tags: haskell

I've been meaning to write my own minimum function just for the sake of possibility exploration (i am new to Haskell).

```
minimum' :: (Ord a) => [a] -> a
minimum' [] = error "empty set - no minimum"
minimum' (x:xs) = if (x <= minimum' xs) then x
```

The thing is, im getting a parser error:

> (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)

Does anyone know whats the problem here? Is this recursive approach even possible?

Thanks a lot for your answers!

Comment: you also will need to handle the single element case `[a]`

Comment: make an interface function: `myMinimum [] = ..... ; myMinimum (x:xs) = minimumAux x xs`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (x <= minimum' xs) then x
```

In haskell the if/else construct as a whole must return a value, so you need a matching else to your if.

Also, Amos Robinson makes a good point, this:

```
minimum' [] = error "empty set - no minimum"
```

will error out when the recursion ends up calling `minimum'` with an empty list. Since you're doing this on your own for practice I won't attempt to fix it, but keep that in mind.

Comment: It might be worth noting that the naive `if x <= minimum' xs then x else minimum' xs` looks like it's computing the minimum twice, but an optimisation called common subexpression elimination will *probably* lift that out so it's only computing it once. Yay purity!

Comment: @AmosRobinson [No, it won't.](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/FAQ#Does_GHC_do_common_subexpression_elimination.3F)

Comment: You can do [this](http://ideone.com/R1RrUy) to avoid computing it twice though can't you?

Comment: Yes. Alternatively one could also define a `min'` function (or use the existing `min` function if allowed) to avoid the `if` altogether.

Comment: Ah, you're right! CSE only works for that case if it's restricted to `a~Int`. We should also note that the []=error makes the inductive case error as well

Comment: @AmosRobinson Good point, I've added a section to my answer :) I had actually fixed that on my local version

Comment: @AmosRobinson you meant to say base case, right? there's base case and recursive case, in a recursive function on an *inductively* defined *datatype*. :)

Comment: @WillNess yes, I guess "the error in the base case makes the recursive case error as well" is probably a better way to put it

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
mini :: Ord a => [a] -> a
mini [] = error "empty set"
mini (x:xs) = foldr (\x y -> if x > y then y else x) x xs
```

Here you don't have the issue with going through the list twice.

Comment: Even if it is a valid solution, it does not answer the question.

Comment: Yes, but the question came up in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, the parser complains that you've forgotten the `else`-part of the `if`-statement. Even if you get the function working, you'll have to define a return value for `minimum' []`. You'd have to return the largest representable value for any given input type, so you'd be restricted to using types that are instances of the `Bounded`-typeclass.

A better way to find the minimum that also doesn't rely on the input being bounded is to simply traverse the list while keeping track of the smallest element encountered so far. In order to keep track of a value, you have to define a helper function, like so:

```
minimum' []     = error "minimum' of empty list"
minimum' (x:xs) = minAux x xs
  where minAux y ys = ...
```

Then, recurse with the helper function.